# How can I obtain just the replacement text from a template I would pass to `String.prototype.replace`?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a project to allow users to perform dynamic regular expression replacements of strings. The primary "mode of operation" is intended to be as follows:

- User enters a search string which includes capture-groups (`(foo)`)
- User enters a replacement string which includes capture-group references (`$1`, `$2`, ...)
- The final output string follows the format of the **replacement string** exactly (somewhat comparable to `printf` string formatting in C), as opposed to the format of the input string.

So, for example, the following parameters/output would be expected:

| What? | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Input | `abc def ghi jkl mno` |
| Search | `(\S+) ghi (\S+)` |
| Replacement (*) | `$1 - $2` |
| Output | `def - jkl` |

(*) It seems the term "replacement" leads to confusion for some. To clarify, this is **NOT** quite the same as a *replacement pattern* such as one used with e.g. `x.replace()`, but more like a formatting / output pattern, or, more verbosely: a pattern where you build an **entirely new string *from scratch***, using references to substrings you've captured with the *search pattern*, ignoring whatever other text is in the original input string. In other words, it's not an inline replacement, but a full replacement.

The idea behind this, is that the user would only have to enter the bare minimum pattern to capture the exact parts they want, rather than (often times) including parts into the search pattern that are just omitted in the replacement.

In the example above, simply adding `.*` to the beginning and end of the *Search* parameter and using `String.prototype.replace()` would essentially accomplish precisely this. However, manipulating the original user-supplied search-string seems like not the best idea, and prone to a lot of gotchas since regex patterns can be quite complex.

So, I was wondering if there are any internal utility functions/methods readily available in JavaScript to safely perform this kind of regex string transformation? I looked around for a while, but maybe I'm just not using the right keywords... Even if there isn't an elegant approach primarily using core JavaScript functions, other (safe!) approaches are still welcome of course.

Comment: You might want to use a 'Worker' to do the regex replacement, that way you can add a timeout.

Comment: You also want to use a try/catch when creating the regex.

Comment: @PoulBak Yes, I do use try-catch already for validation. Also, can you elaborate on why I might want to have a Worker / timeout for performing a string replacement? The software isn't reliant on web connectivity whatsoever. This is for a local desktop application that simply uses JavaScript for extensibility, so it's not like a browser thing.

Comment: Ok, I thought, anyone could enter a regex, which is why I suggested to use a timeout. If you control the regex and make sure there's no 'Catastrophic backtracking' (search for that), then it's fine without timeout.

Comment: @PoulBak I see what you're referring to then, I think. (Un)fortunately, the only one who would be hurt by a 'malicious' regex pattern would be the user themself in this case.

Comment: Adding `.*` in front of and after the regex will not work if you use the `global` flag, which leads to the question: What should happen if the regex is `global` (multiple matches)?

Comment: Well, technically, here it would be `.* (\S+) ghi (\S+) .*` (notice whitespace). Then, whether you use `"abc def ghi jkl mno".replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"), "$1 - $2")` or `"abc def ghi jkl mno".replace(new RegExp(pattern), "$1 - $2")` shouldn't matter - I get the same results at least. Anyway, if you use 'g' flag, the only real difference I see, is that you could potentially get more capture matches, and those should be referenceable. Where you actually do reference those (or *how* you reference them) is completely up to the user..

Comment: I meant: What if `ghi` exists (and matches) multiple times?

Comment: @PoulBak Precisely. It's what I was trying to explain. If the input string is instead `abc ghi ghi ghi mno` and you search for `(\S+) ghi (\S+)` with `g` flag, then the replacement `$1 - $2` should give the output `abc - ghi`, `$2 - $3` should give `ghi - ghi` (given that `$3` exists), `$3 - $4` should give `ghi - mno` (given that `$3` and `$4` exists).

Comment: @user966939 *the replacement `$1 - $2` should give the output `abc - ghi`, `$2 - $3` should give `ghi - ghi` (given that $3 exists), `$3 - $4` should give `ghi - mno` (given that `$3` and `$4` exists).* …What? That’s not remotely how any of this works.

Comment: @user3840170 Are you sure you've read and fully understood the question.. ? The text you quoted doesn't reflect my understanding of how `String.prototype.replace()` works, if that's what you gleaned. This SO question is simply asking for a safe implementation to get, for example, `def - jkl` from a search-pattern `(\S+) ghi (\S+)` and replacement-pattern (maybe "output-pattern" is a better term?) `$1 - $2` with the input `abc def ghi jkl mno`. To clarify, I'm not expecting any particular core JavaScript functions to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are (apparently) looking for is named [GetSubstitution](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-getsubstitution) in the ECMAScript specification, and as of the 13th edition (ECMAScript 2022) it is not exposed directly to user code.  As of writing this answer there is not even a stage-zero proposal to expose it either.  This means that any solution to your problem will necessarily involve either non-portable APIs (the existence of which I am not aware myself), reimplementing GetSubstitution yourself (like in [@jav974’s answer](/a/73084266/3840170)) or the [abstraction inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Abstraction_inversion&oldid=1058366612) anti-pattern like the following:

```js
const getSubstitution = (haystack, needle, replacement) => {
    if (!needle instanceof RegExp)
        throw new TypeError('needle must be a regexp');
    if (needle.global)
        throw new TypeError('global flag must be disabled');
    const needleSticky = new RegExp(
        needle.source, needle.flags.replace('y', '') + 'y');
    const m = needle.exec(haystack);
    if (!m)
        return null;
    needleSticky.lastIndex = m.index;
    const r0 = haystack.replace(needleSticky, replacement);
    return r0.substring(
        m.index, r0.length - (haystack.length - (m.index + m[0].length)));
};

console.log(getSubstitution(
    'abc def ghi jkl mno 123fff45678',
    /(?<ah>\S+) ghi (\S+)/u, '([b4=$`] $1 - $2 $<ah> [af=$\'])'));
```

A version that handles `.global` patterns is even more involved:

```js
const getSubstitutionsGlobal = function* (haystack, needle, replacement) {
    if (!needle instanceof RegExp)
        throw new TypeError('needle must be a RegExp');
    const needleSticky = new RegExp(
        needle.source, needle.flags.replace(/[gy]/g, '') + 'y');
    needle.lastIndex = 0;
    for (const m of haystack.matchAll(needle)) {
        needleSticky.lastIndex = m.index;
        const r0 = haystack.replace(needleSticky, replacement);
        yield r0.substring(
            m.index, r0.length - (haystack.length - (m.index + m[0].length)));
    }
};

console.log(Array.from(getSubstitutionsGlobal(
    'abc def ghi jkl mno 123fff45678 abc 123 ghi 456 mno',
    /(?<ah>\S+) ghi (\S+)/ug, "([b4=$`] $1 - $2 [ah=$<ah>] [af=$'])")));
```

This is inefficient as the pattern is matched against the string twice, once in `RegExp.prototype.exec` and again in `RegExp.prototype[Symbol.replace]` (though this particular inefficiency is ameliorated by using the sticky variant for the latter, so that at least the position of the match is not computed twice), and the `.replace` method concatenates the text surrounding the match only for it to be discarded later.  Expect this solution to perform poorly with long input strings.

Reimplementing GetSubstitution yourself does not run into those problems, and given how strongly backwards-compatible JavaScript engines tend to be, the only way you should expect it to diverge from a native implementation is if a new edition of the language introduces a new flag or gives meaning to previously-invalid RegExp syntax (like happened with named groups), which is the only way the semantics of replacement interpolation could change; but if that happens, there is no telling if the above solution will keep working either.

Comment: Yep, this was what I was looking for. This can even be further simplified in my scenario. Sometimes the easier things are harder than the hard things... Kudos on the ECMAScript reference also.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to support variables such as `$$`, `` $` ``, `$'`, `$@`, `$<name>`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. is to use the `RegExp.prototype.exec` function.

Note: if using the "Global" flag, `g`, then the `` $` `` and `$'` substitutions may not be particularly meaningful.

```js
function replace(regex, flags, s, replacement)
{
    try {
        let matches = [];
        let prefix;
        let suffix;
        let groups;
        let firstTime = true;
        const re = new RegExp(regex, flags);
        for (;;) {
            const m = re.exec(s);
            let i;
            if (firstTime) {
                if (m === null)
                    return null;
                groups = m.groups;
                i = 0;
                prefix = s.substring(0, m.index);
                suffix = s.substring(m.index + m[0].length);
                firstTime = false;
            }
            else if (m === null)
                break;
            else
                i = 1;
            for (; i < m.length; ++i)
                matches.push(m[i]);
            if (re.lastIndex === 0)
                break; // global flag not specified
        }
        let results = [];
        const l = replacement.length;
        for (let index = 0; index < l;) {
            let ch = replacement[index++];
            if (ch != '$') {
                results.push(ch);
            }
            else if (index == l) // invalid
                return null;
            else {
                ch = replacement[index++];
                // saw '$'
                switch (ch) {
                    case '$':
                        results.push('$');
                        break;
                    case '@':
                        results.push(matches[0]);
                        break;
                    case '`':
                        results.push(prefix);
                        break;
                    case "'":
                        results.push(suffix);
                        break;
                    default:
                        index -= 1;
                        const m2 = /(\d+)|<([^>]+)>/.exec(replacement.substring(index));
                        if (m2 === null)
                            return null;
                        index += m2[0].length;
                        if (typeof m2[1] != 'undefined')
                            results.push(matches[parseInt(m2[1])]);
                        else if (typeof(m2[2] != 'undefined'))
                            results.push(groups[m2[2]]);
                        else
                            return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return results.join('');
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
    }
}

const s = 'abc def ghi jkl mno';
const search1 = '(\\S+) ghi (\\S+)';
const search2 = '(?<s1>\\S+) ghi (?<s2>\\S\+)';
const search3 = '(\\w+)';

console.log(replace(search1, '', s, '$1 - $2')); // -> 'def - jkl'
console.log(replace(search2, '', s, '$<s1> - $<s2>')); // -> 'def jkl'
console.log(replace(search1, '', s, "$`-$'")); // -> 'abc - mno'
console.log(replace(search1, '', s, "$@")); // -> 'def ghi jkl'
console.log(replace(search1, '', s, "$$$1$2")); // -> '$defjkl'
console.log(replace(search3, 'g', s, "$5 $4 $3 $2 $1")); // -> 'mno jkl ghi def abc'
```

Comment: Upvoted - thanks for your answer. However, I'd like to clarify that my point in the bounty message was particularly to avoid "double-layering" (i.e. self-rolling) support for references, since new things could potentially be added to the JavaScript regex language beyond what you've manually implemented support for here. For now, I'm keeping my eye out for updates and new answers.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function transform(input, search, replacement) {
    const reg = new RegExp(search);
    const res = reg.exec(input);
    const replacementVars = /\$[\d<a-zA-Z>_-]+/g;
    const vars = new Map();
    const numericRegexp = /^\$(?<value>\d+)$/;
    const stringRegexp = /^\$<(?<value>[\da-zA-Z_-]+)>$/;
    let result;

    while (result = replacementVars.exec(replacement)) {
        let varName = result[0];
        let value;

        // numeric identifier
        if (numericRegexp.test(varName)) {
            value = res[numericRegexp.exec(varName).groups.value];
        }
        // or named identifier
        else if (stringRegexp.test(varName)) {
            value = res.groups[stringRegexp.exec(varName).groups.value];
        }

        vars.set(result[0], value);
    }

    for (const [key, value] of vars) {
        replacement = replacement.replace(key, value);
    }

    return replacement;
}

console.log(transform('abc def ghi jkl mno', /(?<ah>\S+) ghi (\S+)/, '$1 - $2'));
console.log(transform('abc def ghi jkl mno', /(?<ah>\S+) ghi (\S+)/, '$1 - $2 - $<ah>'));
```

Is this more the idea ?